# TypeScript array of generic classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I'm having trouble getting the TypeScript compiler to not give me grief. I have a controller which has an array of classes, NOT the instance of the class, but the class itself. All of these will extend off of the same base, `UnitView`. For some reason I get an error if my `TitleView` does not also accept generics, but I get no errors if it does.

I'm not understanding why `TitleView` would need to accept generics because it passes the Model type explicitly to the `UnitView`. Can anyone explain or see anything that I'm doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
class Model { }
class View<TModel extends Model> {
    private model: TModel;
}

class UnitView<TModel extends Model> extends View<TModel> { }

class TitleView extends UnitView<Model> { }


class Controller {
    private ViewClass: typeof UnitView;

    private ViewClasses: typeof UnitView[] = [
        TitleView
    ]
}
```

And [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Model%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20View%3CTModel%20extends%20Model%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20model%3A%20TModel%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20UnitView%3CTModel%20extends%20Model%3E%20extends%20View%3CTModel%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20TitleView%20extends%20UnitView%3CModel%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Controller%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20ViewClass%3A%20typeof%20UnitView%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20ViewClasses%3A%20typeof%20UnitView%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20TitleView%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D) is a direct link to TypeScript playground if you want to test it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with arrays. Here is a minimal reproduction of your bug:

```
class View<TModel> {
    model: TModel;
}

class UnitView<TModel> extends View<TModel> { }
class TitleView extends UnitView<{}> { }

const example1: typeof UnitView = TitleView; // ERROR
```

`TileView` is *not* assignable to `typeof UnitView`. The key reason being that the type of `T` (a generic) are not compatible with `{}`.

This is similar to the *further simplified* example shown below:

```
class Foo<T> { 
    model: T
}
class Bar{
    model: {}
}

const example2: typeof Foo = Bar; // ERROR
```

## TLDR

Generics `T`  and instances (even `{}`) are not compatible for assignment. This is by design.

## More

The only way to stay compatible is the preserve the `generic` as well e.g.

```
class Foo<T> { 
    model: T
}
class Bar<T>{
    model: T
}

const example3: typeof Foo = Bar; // Okay
```

Comment: So what would be the correct way to write this if I want to express the array will be an array of classes that extend off of UnitView?

Comment: You will have to preserve the generic. Added to answer as `more` 

Comment: I was hoping there'd be another way, as the TitleView really shouldn't be accepting generics, as that is the end of the line and the Model is well-defined at that point. I may just change the typings to an array of any instead. This design seems flawed to me, or maybe I just don't fully understand it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To complement basarat's answer, here's a working declaration:

```
private ViewClasses: (new (...args: any[]) => UnitView<{}>)[] = [
    TitleView
]
```